# Info.plist contained no UIScene configuration dictionary (looking for configuration named "(no name)"

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I am very new to Swift and I am running into this issue on Xcode 14.2

> [14007:8142297] [SceneConfiguration] Info.plist contained no UIScene configuration dictionary (looking for configuration named "(no name)")

I was getting preview until I introduced commented lines below. Since then my preview has been crashing.

```
struct CardView : View{
//    @State
    var isFaceUp: Bool = true
    
    var body: some View{
        ZStack{
            let shape = RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 20)
            if isFaceUp{
                shape.fill().foregroundColor(.white)
                shape.stroke(lineWidth: 3)
                Text("✈️").font(.largeTitle)
                
            } else {
                shape.fill()
            }
        }
//        onTapGesture {
//            isFaceUp = !isFaceUp
//        }
    }
}
```

I tried using lower iOS versions for simulator and creating an empty Scene Configuration as suggested in https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/721912?login=true, but nothing is helping.

My Info.plist:

[image]

I am not able to run the app on preview or simulator if commented lines are removed from above.

Comment: I’m assuming you come from programming using another language. Try the [Apple SwiftUI Tutorials](https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui). You should not make variables of views like you are. Fill and stroke are view modifiers, you can’t use both on the same shape. Also unless you are trying to support iOS 13 you shouldn’t be messing with SceneDelegate code. Views are not like regular objects you can’t use them in the same way. Some of the early WWDC videos might be helpful too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe everyone using recent Xcode/iOS versions is getting those error messages, and they can seemingly be ignored. They definitely aren't causing Preview crashes for me.

Your code is actually very close. If I just uncomment those lines, the only real problem is the absence of a "." in front of the "onTapGesture" view modifier. It feels like a bug that the compiler isn't throwing an error to help you out here.

So the following works for me:

```
struct CardView : View {

    @State
    var isFaceUp: Bool = true

    var body: some View{
        ZStack {
            let shape = RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 20)
            if isFaceUp{
                shape.fill().foregroundColor(.white)
                shape.stroke(lineWidth: 3)
                Text("✈️").font(.largeTitle)

            } else {
                shape.fill()
            }
        }
        .onTapGesture {
            isFaceUp = !isFaceUp
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, It is working now. I cannot believe I spent hours last night trying to figure it out.